# Datatables with ajax and js variable in data doesn't propagate

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm using datatables and data is loaded with AJAX with custom data
but on custom data refrence variable is changed and ajax is reloaded the custom data value is not changed

```
 var range=1;  
var DataTable=$('#tableid_table').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[10,25,50,100, -1], [10,25,50,100, "All"]],
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{ url:'phpqueryfile.php',type: 'POST',dataType: "json","data": {
        "range": select
    }}
} );

$('.range').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("value"));
    select=$(this).attr("value");
    DataTable.ajax.reload();

})
```

when range click is called and range is changed to any other value, ajax is reloaded with range=1

Edit: i managed to send data after changing

```
var select=1;
var DataTable=$('#mygradedcalls_table').DataTable( {

    "lengthMenu": [[10,25,50,100, -1], [10,25,50,100, "All"]],
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{ url:'../Queries_PHP/grad/getAllMyGradedCalls.php',type: 'POST',dataType: "json",data:function (range) {
        Object.assign(range, select);
        return range;
    }
    }
} );

$('.range').click(function () {
    select=$(this).attr("value");
    DataTable.ajax.reload();
})
```

there are two issues
1. first time datatable is loaded no custom data is sent
2. when custom data is sent variable name is "0" and value is select value which is correct but how to change the variable name

Answer (score 0):

i managed to make it work as follows

```
var select=1;
var DataTable=$('#mygradedcalls_table').DataTable( {

    "lengthMenu": [[10,25,50,100, -1], [10,25,50,100, "All"]],
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{ url:'../Queries_PHP/grad/getAllMyGradedCalls.php',type: 'POST',dataType: "json",data:function (d) {
        d.range = select;
    }
    }
} );

$('.range').click(function () {
    select=$(this).attr("value");
    DataTable.ajax.reload();
})
```